# How to install active python in virtual environment on centos

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, activepython

How can i install `ACtive python` in virtual env.

I have this problem as in this post answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458717/1958218

Now that was solved by using active python on centos itself.
But for django , i am using `virtualenv` and i get same problem there. But problem is i dont have active python there.

I tried activating virtual env and then use this command
`/opt/ActivePython-2.6/bin/pypm install mysql-python` but same error

i want to use something like

```
/virtualenv/bin/ActivePython-2.6/bin/pypm install mysql-python
```

Comment: why don't use the regular python that comes with centos ?

Comment: @silviud because it fetches mysql-python 1.2.3 , which does not work for mysql >5.1. but active python gets the latest version. It is working because i tested it. But i don't know how to use that in virtualenv python

Comment: when you set the virtualenv you can tell it where is the binary located - see -p.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell to virtualenv where is your python interpreter

```
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
```